# RegEx split combine successive result .net

Tags: .net, regex, split

I need to split a string based on connectors which can be and or not etc. For ex:

> col1 contains test and not col1 contains test1

I'm using `(and|or)[ ](\bnot\b[ ])?`

It splits correctly but however I want both and not to be under single split.
Currently split returns me And in one array and Not as next array value.

Comment: What is the desired result? (Complex) example please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Split("and not");` Or am I missing somthing?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are looking for something like:

```
\b((?:and|or)(?: not)?)\b
```

Or if you want to handle variable white space:

```
\s*\b((?:and|or)(?:\s+not)?)\b\s*
```